# Python: simple batch rename files in windows folder

Tags: python, windows, rename

Trying to create a simple code, to batch rename a folder in windows.

Musts:

- change every number , like "file02.txt", turn 02 into 0002
- maybe work for every file format, like jpg, png, txt, docx and so on (becuse I'm not sure what will be in the folder, this code might be used for image sequences...)

Is this possible?

I did test versions, combination of the little knowledge I have, but it gets me confused.

my code so far:

```
import os
import sys


folder_path = os.listdir(raw_input("Insert folder path: "))
print "Files in folder: %s" % folder_path

# a split tool
def mysplit(s):
    head = s.rstrip('0123456789')
    tail = s[len(head):]
    return head, tail

# a function to make a new name with needed 0000
def new_filename(filename):
    file_name_part, ext = os.path.splitext(filename) #  file01 and .ext

    original_name, number = mysplit(file_name_part) # 01 and file
    add_zero = number.rjust(4, "0") # add 0001

new_name = original_name + add_zero + ext

print new_name
    # new_name  comes like this ['file0001.txt'] but seperate, not in a list? Why?



for current_file_n in folder_path:
    new = new_filename(current_file_n)
    print list([new]) # trying to make the str into a list....


re_name = os.renames(current_file_n, new)
print re_name
print "Renamed files: %s" % folder_path
```

The desired outcome is the same as the beginning list, but collated with zeros,like this: ['file0001.txt', 'file0002.txt', 'file0003.txt'......'file0015.txt']

I've got errors like windows error: can't find file, and another error; can't connect str and list?

I need an explanation of what I'm doing wrong as simple as possible, or is there another method that I can use that will give me the desired outcome?

Comment: One thing that looks wrong is that your `new_filename()` function doesn't explicitly return anything so effectively returns `None` and your indentation following it is messed-up. This will cause further errors wherever its return value is directly or indirectly used.

Comment: You indentation appears to be messed up because you're using a mixture of tabs and space in you code. It's best to just use spaces (or configure your editor to automatically replace tabs with them).

Comment: @martineau thank you, i didnt realize space and tabs could be a problem

Answer (score 1):

As martineau said your indentation is messed up.

Here's the working code:

```
import os
import sys

# a split tool
def mysplit(s):
    head = s.rstrip('0123456789')
    tail = s[len(head):]
    return head, tail

# a function to make a new name with needed 0000
def new_filename(filename):
    file_name_part, ext = os.path.splitext(filename) #  file01 and .ext

    original_name, number = mysplit(file_name_part) # 01 and file
    add_zero = number.rjust(4, "0") # add 0001

    new_name = original_name + add_zero + ext

    return new_name
    # new_name  comes like this ['file0001.txt'] but seperate, not in a list? Why?

if __name__ == '__main__':
     folder_path = os.listdir(raw_input("Insert folder path: "))
     print "Files in folder: %s" % folder_path
     renamed_files = [] 
     for current_file_n in folder_path:
          new = new_filename(current_file_n)
          renamed_files.append(new) # Add renamed file's name to a list
          try:
               os.renames(current_file_n, new) #It doesn't return anything
               print new
          except:
               print "Unexpected error while renaming %s:%s"%(new, sys.exc_info()[0])
     print "Renamed files: %s" % renamed_files
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @Chrisy: You need to more precise, and specify the exact error and any error message that was displayed.

Comment: @martineau yes, its not much of an error, but the error message : "Unexpected error while renaming im0004.jpg:<type 'exceptions.WindowsError'>" in a row for all files, then there is no rsult of it being renamed...

Comment: @Chrisy: Ahh...I suspect the error is because the script does not check to see if the new filename happens to be the same as the one the file already has — you probably can't rename a file to the name it already has.

Comment: @martineau but isnt "file0001.txt" different from the original "file01.txt"? or does it stop to rename overall when only one of them has the same name?

Comment: @Chrisy: Yes it is, but you said the error message was "while renaming im0004.jpg". You can easily test my theory out by not attempting to rename files `if current_file_n == new:` which makes sense regardless of whether it's the cause of the error (because it's a waste of time even if allowed). One other possibility is that two different filenames would both become the same after the expansion. i.e. "file1.txt" and "file01.txt" both turn into "file0001.txt". Obviously they can't both be renamed to the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be simplified a lot by using regular expression substitution. [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) can take a replacement function. In this case adding leading zeroes to the first number found in the filename.

```
import os, re

def renumber_files(directory, zeroes=4):
    os.chdir(directory)
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        new_name = re.sub(r'\d+', lambda m: m.group().zfill(zeroes), filename, count=1)
        os.rename(filename, new_name)


renumber_files(raw_input("Insert folder path: "))
```

This works because re.sub() can take a callable as the replacement argument.

> ```
> Signature: re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
> ```
>
> Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost non-overlapping
>   occurrences of the pattern in string by the replacement repl.  repl
>   can be either a string or a callable; if a string, backslash escapes
>   in it are processed.  If it is a callable, it's passed the match
>   object and must return a replacement string to be used.

In the lambda `m.group()` returns a string matching the pattern `\d+`. For instance "1", "564645" or "005".

The next step, `str.zfill(4)`, turns those into "0001", "564645", or "0005".

Comment: You should be aware that this could overwrite files. For example: if you have three files `image1.jpg`, `image01.jpg` and `image0001.jpg`, only one of them will be left after running the function. You can check if this is about to happen, and maybe abort or ask for confirmation before you do `os.rename(filename, new_name)`

Comment: Chrisy is using Windows, in which `os.rename` raises an `OSError` if the target name already exists. That doesn't necessarily change your suggestion, but the context is different. You have to handle the exception anyway, given the race condition with competing threads and processes.

Comment: @HåkenLid thank you! it works wonderfully! Can you explain how the steps in re.sub() works ?

Comment: Sure. I've added a short explanation.